# Does the change of dynasty make a country weaker or stronger in the long run?

Tags: society, economy, government, history

When we look at our own history and particularly in China, there were a lot of dynastic changes. Almost all of these changes came with destruction and the death of many people. War also disrupts trade, hurts the economy, and destroys many infrastructures.

Old states tend to get static over time, entrenched in tradition and unable to move forward. On the other hand, changing the rulers can bring a breath of fresh air, a new perspective more able to cope with the actual problems of the time.

In the long run can an old empire stay competitive against other younger states? All states need to adapt but can it be done without overthrowing the rulers over a long period of time?

As an example, I'm trying to imagine what would be different if the Tang Dynasty had not collapsed. Or what would have happened if the Persian Empire had not collapsed. **Could the state regain its splendour?**

Comment: From reading just the title, I was tempted to simply answer "yes".

Comment: Actually, the Persian Empire has collapsed many times, though still refering to its ancient roots (just look at [Iran Air logo](http://skift.com/2013/10/23/the-30-best-looking-airlines-logos-in-the-world/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the other way around. If the dinasty/country is strong, no new claimants can arise.

Particularly China (which you mention) is a good example. when there was a good overall situation, it meant that the ruler had the "Mandate of Heaven" and thus was sacred, but a bad situation meant that the rules had los such mandate and that the kingdom could be claimed for a more "heavenly" leader.

And of course, the change of dinasty does not ensure that things improve, so you will have periods with lots of very short lived dinasties (and rulers); see the fall of the Western Roman Empire. That a courtesan has a gift with setting marriages and poisoning rivals may get him the crown, but that alone will not make him an stadist, improve the economy or stop the barbarians at the gates.

Occasionally the changes of ruler will give the power to an individual able to turn around a situation, but such individuals are very rare (and not inmune to be poisoned by less competent rivals).

And finally, you can get to the situation where the country completely collapses and is replaced by some other country in the same space. There you would confuse yourself talking about "change of dinasties", but the changes would be way deeper (for example, the ascension of Napoleon was not just an issue of "changing the Borbonic dinasty").

Comment: I think "Mandate of Heaven" is specific to China (as are tests to get a position in government bureaucracy). In other countries, peasants endured whichever ruler they had. They did not expect that if dynasty was overthrown, new rules should prove having the mandate by improving life of the common people.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends.  Usually a change in dynasty means that a stronger group has claimed it.  This is often because the current regime is failing in some way.  Often we prop up old systems of doing things merely because we (whoever is keeping the system) are comfortable with it and don't want change.

Humanity has a love hate battle with change.  Stability is good in that it lets people know where things stand and what to expect, freeing them up for other worries; however, too stable and you get stasis, which is deadly to any human construct.  Change is inevitable.  If a construct can't or won't change it will eventually wither and die.  That goes for technology, governments, religion, social norms, etc.

On the other hand, change for change's sake can be just as bad, changing to meet new ideas etc. is good, but upsetting stability just to do so will push things toward chaos, and that can be just as deadly to these same constructs as stasis.

So if a government falls, most often it is because it was lacking somewhere and the new system will correct that (though it might be introducing its own faults).  Learning from the past to not make the sames mistakes in the future and changing with the times will make a dynasty last, fighting for stasis or chaos will see its end sooner than later.

Sorry, rather esoteric here.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, the change of dynasties improves the country. Spanish change from Habsburgs to Borbons helped centralization. French change from Borbons to Bonaparts expanded the nation over half Europe. Egypt endured for 30 dynasties. And China similarly.

Comment: Usually for a dynasty to be vulnerable to takeover, it has to be sucky and the new fellows are likely to be more than average in competence.